# I got a error when compile QMunicate sample i.e. quickblox

Tags: ios, ios8, xcode6, quickblox

The following error is showing when compile.

ld: library not found for -lPods
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Answer (score 0):

Try building to device - Works for me if I build to device but I get the same error when using the simulator.

Hope that works for you as well!

Answer (score 0):

Did you actually do **pod install** to install all pods?

Also you must open *.xcworkspace and not *.xcodeproj

Answer (score 0):

switched gradle to version 1.3.1, that problem vanished

```
dependencies {
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.1 '
}
```